# How to use php fopen() with a non-standard port?

Tags: php, fopen

I need my website to be able to use fopen() to access files on my file streaming server, which our admin has configured to use port 8000. But it errors out and I believe it's because of the port number. **I have allow_url_fopen enabled in php.ini** too, so I don't think that's the issue.

```
Warning: fopen(http://129.237.213.244:8000/mp3/First_8864.mp3) [function.fopen]: 
failed to open stream: Connection refused in _npp_get_mp3() (line 23 of 
/home2/ab83417/public_html/drupal/sites/all/modules/npr_player_pack/npp_library.php).
```

So my question is: Can I somehow tell the webserver or our stream server (icecast, btw) to stop being so picky, or should I use some other php function like curl?

Comment: It seems about right except you must make sure `allow_url_fopen` is enabled in your `php.ini` file.

Comment: The remote server must be refusing connection for some reason, maybe you cannot access `129.237.213.244` from your server, or the remote server is rejecting some of the HTTP headers. You can tell by your exemple that even cURL is failing to retrieve the data.

Comment: "running example" url is dead

Answer (score 1):

You should make sure that you have `allow_url_fopen` set to `1`.

Launch the following script:

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors','1');

echo ini_get('allow_url_fopen')."<br />";
$x = file_get_contents('http://129.237.213.244:8000/mp3/First_8864.mp3');

$y = fopen('http://129.237.213.244:8000/mp3/First_8864.mp3',"rb");
```

It gives me simple `1` and no warnings. If you also get `1` but have warnings you should run the script in other browser and change your ip earlier (for example vpn). It's possible that this site has banned your ip so you cannot connect with this site/url.

Comment: So you should try from other IP. It's quite possible your ip is banned

Comment: Yes, I saw that. So as I mentioned probably your IP is banned, you should try from other IP. I've managed to connect and save file on my PC as mp3 and I can simple open it and listen

Comment: Thank you Marcin, I will try from another IP, but I think it may be a firewall blocking the connection. Our stream server (hosts audio streams as well as mp3s) is located inside the campus network which is likely to blame. I will have to fork the module and rewrite the code to not use fopen. Thanks for the help!

Comment: @DanMantyla But you can use fopen without a problem. I put here 2 methods - `file_get_contents` and `fopen` and with both of them I can connect with this url without a problem